# Why is regex being lazy instead of greedy in this case?

Tags: regex, preg-match

This is a snippet of a complex regex:

```
/\x87([\xA6-\xBf]|\xA6\xF0\x9F)/x
```

Why is it stopping and returning  `\x87\xA6` instead of `\x87\xA6\xF0\x9F`

when matching against a string containing `\x87\xA6\xF0\x9F`  ?

I thought regex was greedy by default and would try to consume the longest pattern?

Or is that only for the `*` and `+` operators?

Is there any way I can force it to look for the longest pattern? Using word boundaries is not an option in this case unfortunately.

---

eta: apparently it works as desired if I move the shorter pattern to the end

```
/\x87(\xA6\xF0\x9F|[\xA6-\xBf])/x
```

is it really that simple and regex is sensitive to order of the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought regex was greedy by default and would try to consume the longest pattern?

"Greediness" refers to the preference of the quantifiers (`?`, `*`, `+`, etc.) for repeating more times rather than fewer. That's not exactly the same as consuming the *longest* substring, though of course it usually works out that way.

The alternation operator `|` also has a preference: it prefers to match what's before the `|`, instead of what's after it. You can fix your pattern by writing:

```
/\x87(\xa6\xF0\x9F|[\xa6-\xbf])/x
```

Comment: Ah you posted just as I was tinkering and discovered that order matters. But it makes me worry as this particular regex pattern is 80 lines long and very easy to make a human mistake of putting a shorter pattern before the longer. I don't suppose there is a flag or other trick I can use to make it search more robustly?

Comment: @ck_: Indeed, with an 80-line pattern, it is very easy to introduce a bug. Unfortunately, there's no relevant concept of "robustness"; if you tell the regex engine that you prefer A over B, there's no way that it can tell that you actually prefer B over A. (More generally, there's no way that a programming language can be "robust" against programmer error and automatically detect and fix your bugs.) I'd suggest eliminating this pattern, e.g. by breaking it into many smaller patterns.

Comment: Excellent answer!  The distinction between greedy *quantifiers* and greedy *regexes* is one that doesn't get mentioned often enough.  Like the meaning of singleline and multiline modes, regex users can go their whole careers without really understanding it.